# Do proxies allow for any type of connection on any port?

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I have a Heroku application running Python that seems to be unable to connect to an external Postgres database. The app uses a proxy tunnel to connect to the database and the proxy itself definitely works, but I'm not sure if the app is using it to connect to connect.

Here are relevant lines of code:
import records as records_client
from apps.socks import Socks5Proxy

```
PROXY_URL='http://username:password@proxyhost:9293'
db_url = 'postgresql://username:password@12.345.6.789:5432/dbname?'

public_ip = requests.get("http://wtfismyip.com/text").text
print('Before proxy: ', public_ip)
# Output: 11.111.1.111

with Socks5Proxy(url=PROXY_URL) as p:
    public_ip = requests.get("http://wtfismyip.com/text").text
    print('Inside proxy: ', public_ip)
    # Output: 22.222.2.222
    
    db = records_client.Database(db_url)
    # FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "11.111.1.111", user "username", database "dbname", SSL off
```

I've made sure that the proxy's IP address is whitelisted to access the database. What's more confusing is why the IP address in the error message has the IP address set before the proxy's context manager.

Here's the definition of `Socks5Proxy` if it helps:

```
import socks
import socket
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


SOCKS5_PORT = 1080

class Socks5Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, url=None, host=None, user=None, password=None):
        if not url and not host:
            raise ValueError('Must supply either a proxy URL or host')

        if url:
            parsed_url = urlparse(url)
            host = parsed_url.hostname
            user = parsed_url.username
            password = parsed_url.password

        socks.set_default_proxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, host, SOCKS5_PORT, True, user, password)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_socket = socket.socket

        self.proxied_socket = socks.socksocket
        logger.debug('Switching from existing socket %s to proxied socket %s', self.old_socket, self.proxied_socket)
        socket.socket = self.proxied_socket
        return self.proxied_socket

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        socket.socket = self.old_socket
        logger.debug('Switching back from proxied socket %s to original socket %s', self.proxied_socket, self.old_socket)
```

This was working previously, so I'm inclined to answer the question in the title as "Yes" but am thrown off by the mismatch in the IP address. How do I check the IP address that's being used in the connection attempt?